# Websphere WAR file name not found Exception

Tags: jdbc, websphere, jndi, web.xml

I have moved a WAR file from Tomcat to Websphere. The WAR file is working perfectly in Tomcat and connects to the database with jndi name. I have configured same jdbc configuration in websphere. When I try to connect the database with the application I am getting errors like this:

```
000000d0 SystemOut     O javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name  not found in context "java:".
at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipbase.NameSpace.getParentCtxInternal(NameSpace.java:1969)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipbase.NameSpace.retrieveBinding(NameSpace.java:1376)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipbase.NameSpace.lookupInternal(NameSpace.java:1219)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipbase.NameSpace.lookup(NameSpace.java:1141)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.urlbase.UrlContextImpl.lookupExt(UrlContextImpl.java:1436)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextImpl.lookupExt(javaURLContextImpl.java:477)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextRoot.lookupExt(javaURLContextRoot.java:485)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextRoot.lookup(javaURLContextRoot.java:370)
at org.apache.aries.jndi.DelegateContext.lookup(DelegateContext.java:161)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:436)
at ConnPoolServlet.getConnection(ConnPoolServlet.java:65)
at ConnPoolServlet.service(ConnPoolServlet.java:25)
```

Can you please suggest how to make my WAR file to work with jndi name in Websphere application server?

Comment: You need to show us the code of `ConnPoolServlet.getConnection(..)`. It seems you are trying to lookup for some resource without a name. There should be the name of the resource you are looking for between the words `Name` and `not found..`in the message

Answer (score 0):

How are you connecting to the DataSource. You will need to use InitialContext lookup (with WsInitialNaming , iiop server address binding with the right principal etc.
) and connect to the datasource in WAS which is slightly different from how it is usually done on Tomcat.

Also additionally you may also want to execute dumpNamespace to see if there is a JNDI binding that is available for DataSource and Connection pool to lookup and use

Comment: can you try the lookup without the prefix just : jdbc/danone . I am assuming you did test connection in the admin console and it works

Comment: Hi Ramachandran, issue got fixed with java:comp/.. . Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

In case of direct JNDI lookup without resource reference, Tomcat allows direct lookup with `java:comp/env/` prefix whereas WAS doesn't. Use `jdbc/datasource` (without prefix) for WAS in `ConnPoolServlet.getConnection(..)`

Comment: That's completely incorrect. WAS is using java:comp/env for resource references, and that is recommended practice to access server resources. Maybe resource reference is incorrectly defined in the application.

Comment: The answer is correct for direct lookup without resource reference. The question states "The WAR file is working perfectly in Tomcat and connects to the database with jndi name" indicating a strong case of a direct lookup. The answer is incomplete but not incorrect. Could you please undo the down vote?

Comment: Make that answer complete, and explain that in case of Tomcat for direct lookup it allows java:comp then I'll undo. As in current form it is misleading and incomplete.